# How to group suggestions nested list in the primeng autocomplete angular 8

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I am trying to group the autocomplete suggestions and would like to render them in primeng.

How we can add a custom template in primeng?

my data

```js
data = [{"id":"m1","name":"menu1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"d1","name":"datanested1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"1","name":"direct Data","val":"E"},{"id":"2","name":"test","val":"E"}]}]},{"id":"d2","name":"menu2","val":"D","items":[{"id":"21","name":"test21","val":"E"},{"id":"22","name":"test23","val":"E"}]},{"id":"d3","name":"menu3","val":"D","items":[{"id":"31","name":"test data 3","val":"E"},{"id":"32","name":"test data 4","val":"E"}]}]
```

Is there any other libraries available in angular 8 which support this?

I would like to achieve something like this when users start searching in autocomplete...

```js
Menu1 - header
 datanested1 -subheader
  direct Data -values
   test        -values

Menu2 - header
 test21-values
 test23-values

Menu3 - header
 test data 3-values
 test data 4-values


1. if the user types "direct" in the input box...

Menu1 - header
 datanested1 -subheader
  direct Data -values

2. if the user types "data" in the input box...

Menu3 - header
 test data 3-values
 test data 4-values

3. if the user types "menu" in the input box...
Menu1 - header
 datanested1 -subheader
  direct Data -values
  test        -values

Menu2 - header
 test21-values
 test23-values

Menu3 - header
 test data 3-values
 test data 4-values
```

[image]

I have tried the following example in stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-qtsnpm

Comment: How do you decide what group would be for each item. Does your item have some GroupNumber or GroupName property?

Comment: An alternative library would be angular material. I would actually suggest angular material over primeng in most scenarios tbh. I think it integrates much better (duh) and also has some great components such as this one. https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below approach we will reduce the array to a simple structure

```json
[
  {
    "id": "m1",
    "name": "menu1",
    "val": "D",
    "search": ["m1", "d1", "1", "2", "menu1", "datanested1", "direct Data", "test"],
    "depth": 2
  },
  {
    "id": "d1",
    "name": "datanested1",
    "val": "D",
    "search": ["d1", "1", "2", "datanested1", "direct Data", "test"],
    "depth": 1
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "direct Data",
    "val": "E",
    "search": ["1", "direct Data"
    ],
    "depth": 0
  },
 ...

]
```

The idea is this, we will use the `depth` to format out text while the `search` for searching.

```typescript
  maxDepth = 0;
  reducedArray = (arr, depth = 0, parentSearch = []) => {
    this.maxDepth = Math.max(this.maxDepth, depth);
    if (!arr) {
      return [];
    }

    return arr.reduce((prev, { items, ...otherProps }) => {
      // const depth = this.findDepth({ items, ...otherProps });
      const search = [
        ...this.getProps({ items, ...otherProps }, "id"),
        ...this.getProps({ items, ...otherProps }, "name")
      ];
      const newParentSearch = [...parentSearch, otherProps.name, otherProps.id];
      return [
        ...prev,
        { ...otherProps, search, depth, parentSearch },
        ...this.reducedArray(items, depth + 1, newParentSearch)
      ];
    }, []);
  };

  getProps = (item, prop) => {
    if (!item.items) {
      return [item[prop]];
    } else {
      return [
        item[prop],
        ...item.items.map(x => this.getProps(x, prop))
      ].flat();
    }
  };
```

We can apply styles like below

```typescript
  getStyle(depth) {
    return {
      color: depth === 0 ? "darkblue" : depth === 1 ? "green" : "black",
      paddingLeft: depth * 7 + "px",
      fontWeight: 800 - depth * 200
    };
  }
```

I will use reactive programming so I will convert the object to an Observable usinf `of` operator

```typescript
  data$ = of(this.reducedArray(this.data));
  filteredData$ = combineLatest([this.data$, this.filterString$]).pipe(
    map(([data, filterString]) =>
      data.filter(
        ({ search, parentSearch }) =>
          !![...search, ...parentSearch].find(x => x.includes(filterString))
      )
    )
  );
```

We now done, the remaining is to update html

```html
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="cdsidvalue" [suggestions]="filteredData$ | async"
  (completeMethod)="filterString$.next($event.query)" field="name" [size]="16" placeholder="Menu" [minLength]="1">
  <ng-template let-menu pTemplate="item">
    <span 
      [ngStyle]="getStyle(menu.depth)" >{{ menu.name }}</span>
  </ng-template>

</p-autoComplete>
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-pofce9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

### Update

Since we are using reactive programming, refactoring to accept http requests is quite easy, simply replace the observable with an http request

```typescript
data$ = this.http.get<any[]>("my/api/url");
  filteredData$ = combineLatest([this.data$, this.filterString$]).pipe(
    map(([data, filterString]) =>
      this.reducedArray(data).filter(
        ({ search, parentSearch }) =>
          !![...search, ...parentSearch].find(x => x.includes(filterString))
      )
    )
  );
```

[See this update in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-y9ggte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I have also updated the html to add loading message, we do not want to display a form without data

Comment: Thanks a lot... It works like charm... But when I type menu in searchbox and if it matches parent header... I would like to show all related header with parent elements such as.... if the user types "menu" in the input box...
Menu1 - header
 datanested1 -subheader
  direct Data -values
  test        -values

Menu2 - header
 test21-values
 test23-values

Menu3 - header
 test data 3-values
 test data 4-values

Comment: Is it possible to show nested values if input matches parent elements?

Comment: Same way if user type "datanested" Menu1 - header
 datanested1 -subheader
  direct Data -values
  test        -values

Comment: Thanks, Owen.. while implementing this feature... I was waiting for services to give me data at that situation how I can wait for data$ to get updated after service response?

Comment: I do get following error : property is used before its initialization

Comment: Check update solution. For property used before initialization just move it up the class

Comment: 2. if the user types "data" in the input box...

Menu3 - header not clickable
 test data 3-values clickable
 test data 4-values clickable

Comment: 3. if the user types "menu" in the input box...
Menu1 - header -not clickable
 datanested1 -subheader -not clickable
  direct Data -values- clickable
  test        -values - clickable

Menu2 - header - not clickable
 test21-values - clickable
 test23-values-  clickable

Menu3 - header - not  clickable
 test data 3-values -  clickable
 test data 4-values - clickable

Comment: I can create a new question if you want... Owen Kelvin

Comment: Give me a few hrs, held up with a deadline will update this solution

Comment: updated. (2nd change)... can we make the header not clickable if it has nested data, same for subheader not clickable if it has nested data... examples are above.

Comment: able to resolve the clear issue, now only looking for restrictions on click and hover based on header/subheader...

Comment: Any luck for above scenario? Owen?

Comment: was able to come up with this, at least visually it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-y9ggte

Comment: Thanks, Owen.. it is working for hover but still, I am able to click on the menus and it shows MouseEvent {isTrusted: true} in console when I clicked... it is possible to block that?

Comment: Unfortunately I have been unable to restrict that, will debug more

Comment: Sure thanks. Even if we can keep open suggestion list after clicking for menu.. it will work too. Can we try that?

Comment: any luck.. Owen?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-y9ggte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html working on it, only background remaining, clicking on parent now does not select item

Comment: Everything fixed, check now

Comment: can you please help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125986/is-it-possible-to-export-dropdown-list-to-excelwill-create-dropdown-in-excel-i

Answer (score 1):

**Patel** , Yes you can add Group Header in NgPrime

**.ts**

```
adminentrylistSearch = [
{
  Grp_Header:'THIS IS Header 1' ,
  cdsid: "0121",
  firstname: "FirstName1",
  lastname: "LastName1",
  fullname: "LastName1, FirstName1"
},
{
  cdsid: "0122",
  firstname: "FirstName1",
  lastname: "LastName2",
  fullname: "LastName2, FirstName2"
},
{
  cdsid: "0123",
  firstname: "FirstName3",
  lastname: "LastName3",
  fullname: "LastName3, FirstName3"
},
{
  Grp_Header:'THIS IS Header 2',
  cdsid: "0124",
  firstname: "FirstName4",
  lastname: "LastName4",
  fullname: "LastName4, FirstName4"
},
{
  cdsid: "0125",
  firstname: "FirstName5",
  lastname: "LastName5",
  fullname: "LastName5, FirstName5"
},
{
  cdsid: "0126",
  firstname: "FirstName6",
  lastname: "LastName6",
  fullname: "LastName6, FirstName6"
},
{
  cdsid: "0127",
  firstname: "FirstName7",
  lastname: "LastName7",
  fullname: "LastName7, FirstName7"
}
```

];

**.html**

```
<p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="cdsidvalue" [suggestions]="filteredCountriesSingle" [dropdown]="true"
  (completeMethod)="filterCountrySingle($event)" field="firstname" [size]="16" placeholder="CDSID">
  <ng-template let-adminentrylistSearch [ngIf]="adminentrylistSearch.index" pTemplate="text">
    <div class='unclickable-header'>
      <span [style.font-weight]="adminentrylistSearch.Grp_Header ? 'bold' : null"> {{adminentrylistSearch.Grp_Header ? adminentrylistSearch.Grp_Header : adminentrylistSearch.firstname}} </span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-autoComplete>
```

Check Result here...
[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-7-1-2-hsphw1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: How it will support nested structure? [{"id":"m1","name":"menu1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"d1","name":"datanested1","val":"D","items":[{"id":"1","name":"direct Data","val":"E"},{"id":"2","name":"test","val":"E"}]}]},{"id":"d2","name":"menu2","val":"D","items":[{"id":"21","name":"test21","val":"E"},{"id":"22","name":"test23","val":"E"}]},{"id":"d3","name":"menu3","val":"D","items":[{"id":"31","name":"test data 3","val":"E"},{"id":"32","name":"test data 4","val":"E"}]}]

Comment: here menu1,menu2,menu3 is main header

Answer (score 0):

In your primeng version (7.1.2) grouped autocomplete is not supported. But it's supported in latest version(11.3.0). Please see below image and follow https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/autocomplete

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there any way I can add a custom template and create the groups?

Comment: You want that in 7.1.2 version only?

Comment: Yes as I do have angular 7 version in my application

Comment: Angular version 7 is ok. In that you can try to install version 11.3.0 of primeng and try to follow the above link. Because in primeng 7.1.2 there is no option to group autocomplete

Comment: the latest version of primeng is not supporting in angular 7