# How to close the existing ngx-modal when new modal open up from same component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-modal

I am trying to make a reusable modal component that can be called from the same modal itself.

How I can configure the component and modal such that when the reusable component opens up the older instance will get closed directly?

Below is my stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-component-modal-ngx-bootstrap-n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use one modal...

Here is the strategy

1. Have the modal on the app component
2. Create a service that will communicate when user would like to open an new modal
3. From each of the component buttons call the service

Lets begin by defining our Service

### my.service.ts

```typescript
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject } from "rxjs";

interface IModalParams {
  component: any;
  config?: any;
  title?: any;
}
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  modalOpen$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  component;
  config;
  title;
  show({ component, config, title }: IModalParams) {
    this.component = component;
    this.config = config;
    this.title = title;
    this.modalOpen$.next(true);
  }
}
```

So we have defined a show method that will set some variabes (`component`, `configuration` and `title`)

We have also defined a subject `modalOpen$`. Now any property that subscribes to this will be informed when a user has opened a new modal

### app.component.ts

```typescript
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.modalOpen$.pipe(
      tap(() => this.modalRef?.hide()),
      filter(isOpen => isOpen)
    ).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        const {component, config, title} = this.myService
          this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(component, config);
          if(title) {
            this.modalRef.content.title = title; 
          }
      }
    })
  }
```

Here we subscribe to `modalOpen$` and open or close the component provided

### any-other.component.ts

```typescript
 this.myService.show({
     component: ModalContentComponent,
     config: {
      ignoreBackdropClick: false
    },
    title: "Modal with component"
   })
  }
```

In other components, we can now use our `show` method as specified above

[See Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-component-modal-ngx-bootstrap-n-ogj88d?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: But is it good practice to keep the subscription on in app.component?

Comment: As long as you ensure to unsubscribe I believe its fine. Another option would be to simply move the modal to its own component. that way you wouldn't have to worry about subscribing in the app.component

Comment: Cool. Is it possible for you to provide the example of modal as own component...? Thanks in advance

Comment: see this fork https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-component-modal-ngx-bootstrap-n-6xdtaq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks..just one suggestion.. do you know any Library who supports this function like material in Angular 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802189/how-to-add-arrows-for-left-and-right-navigations-in-primeng-tab-view-in-angular

Comment: @app one way would be to create your own directive, I have provided a solution, kindly check

Comment: Thanks a lot Owen.. you are life saver... One more question if you can help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66570025/how-to-group-suggestions-list-in-the-primeng-autocomplete-angular-8/66740654#66740654

Comment: Any luck @owen ?

Comment: @a.p.patel have a look, I have provided my approach

Comment: @OwenKelvin thanks a lot.. modal component approach is really nice. but can we make it configurable for a specific component for future use?

Comment: @app I believe its already configurable, Passing different config values to the `show()` function should bring about different configurations

Comment: Is there any way we can configure for some component we can close instance right away vs for some component we can use multiple instances?