# Update the count of searched results and change the selection based on the number of time user searched in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I would like to add a function in which users can go to the next searched result. Thanks, @ggorlen for helping with the recursive search.

[image]

I have a recursive search function that gives the first value and makes them **selected = true** and if it is in nested array make **showTree=true**.

- How I can add a function in which if the user clicks the next search record then the selected: true will set to the next result and remove the previous one?
- and based on the new results showTree will change.
- How to add a variable which gets updated based on the number of time search is called...
- previous record option so user can go back to the previous result

```js
const expandPath = (nodes, targetLabel) => {
  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (node.label.includes(targetLabel)) {
      return (node.selected = true);
    } else if (expandPath(node.item, targetLabel)) {
      return (node.showTree = true);
    }
  }
};

// Output

expandPath(testData, 'ch');

//// add variable for count  example: 1 of 25

console.log(testData);

//if user click on nextrecord after search


//nextrecord(){
//logic to remove the selected true from current and add for next
//update showtree
//update recordNumber of totalValue example: 2 of 25
//}


//child3 should get selected true and remove child1 selected true and showtree
//same add showTree= true based on selected value

//if user click on previous record after search

//previousrecord(){
//logic to remove the selected true from current and add for previous
//update showtree
//update recordNumber of totalValue example: 1 of 25
//}



console.log(testData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// Test Data
const testData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'parent1',
    item: [
      {
        id: 21,
        label: 'child1',
        item: [
          {
            id: 211,
            label: 'child31',
            item: [
              {
                id: 2111,
                label: 'child2211',
                item: [{ id: 21111, label: 'child22111' }]
              }
            ]
          },
          { id: 222, label: 'child32' }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        label: 'child2',
        item: [
          {
            id: 221,
            label: 'child421',
            item: [{ id: 2211, label: 'child2211' }]
          },
          { id: 222, label: 'child222' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'parent2',
    item: [
      {
        id: 21,
        label: 'child2',
        item: [
          {
            id: 511,
            label: 'child51',
            item: [
              {
                id: 5111,
                label: 'child5211',
                item: [{ id: 51111, label: 'child52111' }]
              }
            ]
          },
          { id: 522, label: 'child352' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you might want a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)

Comment: I can go with the next record method which will be called when the user wants to see other records. so they can click next and previous records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refer following code

```
    const testData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'parent1',
    item: [
      {
        id: 21,
        label: 'child1',
        item: [
          {
            id: 211,
            label: 'child31',
            item: [
              {
                id: 2111,
                label: 'child2211',
                item: [{ id: 21111, label: 'child22111' }]
              }
            ]
          },
          { id: 222, label: 'child32' }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        label: 'child2',
        item: [
          {
            id: 221,
            label: 'child421',
            item: [{ id: 2211, label: 'child2211' }]
          },
          { id: 222, label: 'child222' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'parent2',
    item: [
      {
        id: 21,
        label: 'child2',
        item: [
          {
            id: 511,
            label: 'child51',
            item: [
              {
                id: 5111,
                label: 'child5211',
                item: [{ id: 51111, label: 'child52111' }]
              }
            ]
          },
          { id: 522, label: 'child352' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

// flatten down tree to array and add parent pointer
const flatten = (data) => {
  let flattenData = [data]
  if (data.item) {
    for (const item of data.item) {
      item.parent = data;
      flattenData = flattenData.concat(flatten(item));
    }
  }
  return flattenData;
}

let flattenData = [];

// flatten down the test data
for (const data of testData) {
  flattenData = flattenData.concat(flatten(data));
}

// to update showTree flag
const toggle = (item, expand = true) => {
  const parent = item.parent;
  if (parent) {
    parent.showTree = expand;
    if (parent.parent) {
      return toggle(parent, expand);
    }
    return parent;
  }
  return item;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {targetLabel} query 
 * @returns function navigate with param forward flag
 */
const seach = (query) => {
  let index = -1;
  const items = flattenData.filter(x => x.label.includes(query));
  return (forward = true) => {
    if (index > -1) {
      items[index].selected = false;
      toggle(items[index], false);
    }
    index = index + (forward ? 1 : -1);
    let item = null;
    if (index > -1 && index < items.length) {
      items[index].selected = true;
      item = toggle(items[index], true);
    }
    return {
      item,
      index,
      length: items.length
    }
  }
}

const navigate = seach('child5211');

// next result
let result = navigate();

// previous result
result = navigate(false);

// result will look like this
/**
 * {
 *  item: root of current item with showTree and selected falgs or null if out of bound,
 *  index: current match,
 *  length: total match
 * }
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

Tackling one thing at a time here, you can pretty quickly get the desired 'next' functionality you want by converting you're recursive search to a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

```js
function* expandPath(nodes, targetLabel) {
  for (const node of nodes) {
    if (node.label.includes(targetLabel)) {
      yield (node.selected = true);
    } else if (expandPath(node.item, targetLabel)) {
      yield (node.showTree = true);
    }
  }
};

const gen = expandPath(mynodes, "thisTargetLabel");
gen.next()
gen.next() //<-- the next one
```

---

It's a little hard to know without more of your context how to answer the other questions, but what it really seems like you need here is *state*, and (es6) class is a good way to make this:

```js
class Searcher {
  constructor(mynodes, mylabel){
    this.count=0;
    this.nodes=mynodes;
    this.label=mylabel;
    this.generateMatches(this.nodes);
    this.selectNode(this.matches[0]); // select the first node
  }

  generateMatches(nodes){
      this.matches=[];
    for (const node of nodes) {
      if (node.label.includes(this.label)) {
        this.matches.push(node);
      } else {
        this.generateMatches(nodes.node) 
      }
    }
  }

  updateTreeById(id, node){
    this.nodes.forEach(n=>n.showTree = false);
    for (const node of this.nodes) {
      if (node.id === id) {
        //noop but we are here
      } else if(this.updateTreeById(id, this.nodes.node)) {
        node.showTree = true;
      }
    }
  }

  selectNode(i){
    const index =  i % this.matches.length;
    this.currNodeId =  this.matches[index].id;
    this.matches[index].selected = true // we are wrapping around
    this.count = i; // setting your current count
    this.updateTreeById(this.matches[index].id)
    // update logic, reset trees
  }

  nextNode(){
    this.selectNode(this.count + 1)
  }
  prevNode(){
    this.selectNode(this.count - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I have updated my UI and I am using angular in the frontend.